# Cucumber Cleanup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, integration-testing

SO Folk,

Anyone around these parts know if you can keep Cucumber from cleansing test data at the end of a run? I've a few tests that continue to fail and I'd like to have a look at the data backing those tests...

Any ideas?

Thanks!
Cory Wilkerson

Comment: You might need to explain a little more with examples.  What are you trying to do? What do you mean by "cleansing"?  Can you run the tests individually and get a good result?  Is the whole suite failing?

Comment: Sorry - thought that was pretty clear. I'm not having an issue with Cucumber itself, not at all. Tests are running as I expect. I was just curious If I could keep Cucumber from truncating/purging test data that is created during the Cucumber tests from my local db so that I could better investigate the cause of test failures (not Framework/Cucumber failures).

Thanks for the downvote.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your `features/support/env.rb` file there are some comments about this. If you don't want to roll-back the database after a particular scenario has finished then add the `@no-txn` tag to the scenario. You will then need to clean the db yourself. The easiest way is to do a `db:test:clone`.

The best way to troubleshoot your issues would be to run the problem scenarios individually and see how each one is failing. If you do a run and have scenarios leaving data in the DB then you are going to cause yourself all kinds of problems. Once you have fixed the scenario then do a `db:test:clone` before you work on the next one or do a run.

Comment: Thanks Joseph - precisely what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Here's the definitino for the debug step I mentioned in the comment to Sam Livingston-Gray:

```
When /I want to debug/i do
  debugger
  true # never put debugger at the end of a method
end
```

Answer (score 1):

A bit hackish, but as a last resort, maybe you could add a Then block called "Then pause tests" that either halts, or goes into a polling loop and doesn't continue until it sees some condition change (e.g., you touch /features/continue.txt)?

Stick "Then pause tests" in the test you want to look at, and you've got a way to inspect the database before it continues.  Of course, this doesn't work if Cucumber uses database transactions...

(Sorry for the vagueness; it's been a while since I last used Cucumber.)